# position of checkbox get change

Tags: android, checkbox, filter

I am trying to apply filter on my custom adapter which extends BaseAdapter, in which I am facing some problems, after I filter input based on the text in EditText and check the CheckBox to select one value and if I erase the text in the EditText to search for some other thing the position of the checked checkbox changes.

**MainActivty**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    EditText searchText;

    ArrayList<String> phno0 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> arrayListNames;
    // private ListView listview;
    // private EditText edittext;
    public List<ProfileBean> list;
    public SearchableAdapter adapter;
    ProfileBean bean;

    String[] cellArray = null;
    String contacts;
    ListView lv;
    String phoneNumber, name;

    // StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(
                Color.parseColor("#00aef0"));

        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
        setContentView(R.layout.get);
        // mStatusView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
        searchText = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        list = new ArrayList<ProfileBean>();

        getAllCallLogs(this.getContentResolver());

        adapter = new SearchableAdapter(getApplicationContext(), list);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        contacts = SmsSend.contacts;

        if (SmsSend.contacts != null) {
            cellArray = contacts.split(";");
            //contacts=null;
            // Toast.makeText(getApplication(), contacts.toString(),
            // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            for (int i = 0; i < cellArray.length; i++) {

                for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {

                    if (cellArray[i].equals(list.get(j).getNumber())) {
                        adapter.setChecked(j, true);

                        // break;
                    }
                }

            }
        }



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contact_main, menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case android.R.id.home:
            //StringBuilder checkedcontacts = new StringBuilder();
            // System.out.println(".............." +
            // adapter.mCheckStates.size());
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)

            {
                if (adapter.mCheckStates.get(i) == true) {
                    phno0.add(list.get(i).getNumber());
                    //checkedcontacts.append(list.get(i).toString());
                //  checkedcontacts.append("\n");
                    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    // list.get(i).getNumber().toString(),
                    // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("..Not Checked......"
                            + list.get(i).getNumber().toString());
                }

            }

            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            returnIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("name", phno0);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);

            finish();
            break;

        case R.id.addPage:

            break;
        case R.id.action_search:

            searchText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            searchText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                        int count) {
                    adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
                }
            });
            break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
phno0.clear();
        //StringBuilder checkedcontacts = new StringBuilder();
        // System.out.println(".............." + adapter.mCheckStates.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)

        {
            if (adapter.mCheckStates.get(i) == true) {
                phno0.add(list.get(i).getNumber());

            } else {
                System.out.println("..Not Checked......"
                        + list.get(i).getNumber().toString());
            }

        }

        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        returnIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("name", phno0);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);

        finish();

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            adapter.toggle(position);


    }

    public void getAllCallLogs(ContentResolver cr) {

        Cursor phones = cr.query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
                null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME
                        + " ASC");
        while (phones.moveToNext()) {
            phoneNumber = phones
                    .getString(phones
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            name = phones
                    .getString(phones
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));

            list.add(new ProfileBean(name, phoneNumber));

        }
        phones.close();
    }
}
```

**SearchableAdapter**

```
public class SearchableAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable, OnCheckedChangeListener {

    public SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates;
    private List<ProfileBean>originalData = null;
    private List<ProfileBean>filteredData = null;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter();

    public SearchableAdapter(Context context, List<ProfileBean> data) {
        //mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(filteredData.size());
        mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(data.size());
        this.filteredData = data ;
        this.originalData = data ;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return filteredData.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return filteredData.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

         ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);


                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                holder.number = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                holder.chk = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
                holder.chk.setTag(position);
                convertView.setTag(R.layout.row,holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(R.layout.row);
            }
            holder.chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

            holder.chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

            ProfileBean bean = filteredData.get(position);
            holder.name.setText(bean.getName());
            holder.number.setText(bean.getNumber());
            convertView.setTag(bean);
            return convertView;
        }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        TextView number;
        CheckBox chk;
    }

    public boolean isChecked(int position) {

        return mCheckStates.get(position, false);
    }

    public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
        mCheckStates.put(position, isChecked);
    }

    public void toggle(int position) {
        setChecked(position, !isChecked(position));
    }



    public Filter getFilter() {
        return mFilter;
    }

    private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            final List<ProfileBean> list = originalData;

            int count = list.size();
            final ArrayList<ProfileBean> nlist = new ArrayList<ProfileBean>(count);

            String filterableString ;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

                ProfileBean bean =  list.get(i);
                filterableString = bean.getName();
                if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                    nlist.add(bean);
                }
            }

            results.values = nlist;
            results.count = nlist.size();

            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            filteredData = (ArrayList<ProfileBean>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }





    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mCheckStates.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);
    }




}
```

**ProfileBean Class**

```
public class ProfileBean {
    private String name;
    private String number;
    //private boolean checked = false ;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }


    public ProfileBean(String name, String number) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;

    }



        }
```

Comment: You are using sparsebooleanarray which is stores based on the position..so when you filter your list items positions will be cahnged and after erase it will get to normal positions but old positions with filtered list is saved which is creating problem here..is it confusing or understand??

Comment: @  kalyan pvs ,i got it,but if i not use the sparsebooleanarray,then how will i retrieve the values in mainactivity onbackpress..??

Comment: For this take a boolean variable in ProfileBean class and based on checkedposition change the value of ProfileBean object in adapter..that list is also available for the Activity..

Comment: can you tell me with an example..plzz

Comment: ok..wait i will edit your code and post..meanwhile post your ProfileBean class..

Comment: yes..i post the bean class too

Comment: @  kalyan pvs there..???

Comment: yes posted my answer change your code like taht and try..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Adapter like this..

```
public class SearchableAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable,
    OnCheckedChangeListener {

public SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates;
private List<ProfileBean> originalData = null;
private List<ProfileBean> filteredData = null;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter();

public SearchableAdapter(Context context, List<ProfileBean> data) {
    // mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(filteredData.size());
    mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(data.size());
    this.filteredData = data;
    this.originalData = data;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public int getCount() {
    return filteredData.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return filteredData.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.number = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        holder.chk = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        holder.chk.setTag(position);
        convertView.setTag(R.layout.row, holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(R.layout.row);
    }

    ProfileBean bean = filteredData.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(bean.getName());
    holder.number.setText(bean.getNumber());
    holder.chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
    holder.chk.setChecked(bean.isChecked);
    holder.chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    convertView.setTag(bean);
    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView name;
    TextView number;
    CheckBox chk;
}

public void toggle(int position) {
    ProfileBean bean = filteredData.get(position);
    bean.isChecked = !bean.isChecked;
}

public android.widget.Filter getFilter() {
    return mFilter;
}

private class ItemFilter extends android.widget.Filter {

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

        String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        final List<ProfileBean> list = originalData;

        int count = list.size();
        final ArrayList<ProfileBean> nlist = new ArrayList<ProfileBean>(
                count);

        String filterableString;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            ProfileBean bean = list.get(i);
            filterableString = bean.getName();
            if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(
                    filterString.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                nlist.add(bean);
            }
        }

        results.values = nlist;
        results.count = nlist.size();

        return results;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
            FilterResults results) {
        filteredData = (ArrayList<ProfileBean>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int position = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
    ProfileBean profileBean = filteredData.get(position);
    profileBean.isChecked = isChecked;
    // mCheckStates.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);

}
}
```

and your bean class like..

```
public class ProfileBean {
private String name;
private String number;
public boolean isChecked;

// private boolean checked = false ;
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public void setNumber(String number) {
    this.number = number;
}

public ProfileBean(String name, String number) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.number = number;

}

}
```

And keep remaining same..try like this and let know if any problem..

Change your onBkpress method like this..

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    phno0.clear();
    for (ProfileBean bean : list) {
        if (bean.isChecked) {
            phno0.add(bean.getNumber());
        } else {
            System.out.println("..Not Checked......"
                    + list.get(i).getNumber().toString());
        }
    }

    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    returnIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("name", phno0);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);

    finish();
}
```

Comment: Thats for importing the classes..or using other Filter class??

Comment: i did as per your saying,but it is not returning values onbackpress now

Comment: @good to hear..try to optimize your code..there is lot of object you are creating..